# How can I render a quarto book after setting date-format in YAML?

Tags: r, yaml, rstudio, quarto

I am trying to create a quarto book in RStudio. When I add date-format in the YAML, the book cannot be rendered. When I remove the date-format field, I can render it successfully. A sample YAML specification (in `_quarto.yml` file of the project) is as follows:

```
project:
  type: book

book:
  title: "A Sample Book Title"
  author: 
    - name: "Eva"
  date: today
  #date-format: "MMM D, YYYY"
  page-footer:
    border: true
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - intro.qmd
    - summary.qmd
    - references.qmd

bibliography: references.bib
nocite: |
  @*

format:
  html:
    theme: cosmo
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    fig-align: center
    fig-width: 6
    fig-height: 5
    fig-pos: 'h'
    fig-cap-location: bottom
    tbl-cap-location: top
    pdf-engine: lualatex
    keep-tex: true
    linestretch: 1.5
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 2
    toc-title: Contents
    lof: true
    lot: true
    number-sections: true
    number-depth: 6
    colorlinks: true
    cite-method: biblatex
    csl: apa7.csl
    callout-appearance: simple
    callout-icon: true
```

When I keep date-format field commented, I can render this book in any format (HTML/PDF), but when I uncomment date-format, I cannot render it to any format.

My quarto version is `1.2.90`, and RStudio version is

```
RStudio 2022.11.0-daily+170 "Elsbeth Geranium" Daily (7d3b494aefefb25c1b943137678c620c3b60a736, 2022-09-08) for Windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2022.11.0-daily+170 Chrome/102.0.5005.167 Electron/19.0.10 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: I have tested with the `date-format` with quarto version `1.0.38`. It worked as intended. Can you try with that version  so that you can be sure whether its a version specific problem.?

Comment: I am sure it is version-specific. Earlier in another book project, I could render the book in PDF. But I can't render that book also now.

Comment: Then it would be best to open a issue on the quarto github repo to let the quarto devs know this problem.

Comment: Quarto 1.2.90 is a pre-release version. Why not go with the latest official release 1.1.189 (where anything works fine)?

Comment: I just observed that I can render it using quarto 1.2.64, but not with later versions. @Martin C.Arnold I want to experiment with the newer versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate as Issue in Quarto: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/2398

Comment: @cderv Yes, it seems the same issue. But I still cannot render it even after upgrading to quarto 1.2.102. Is this patched only in the stable release?

Comment: It has been merged in v1.2.108 not v1.2.102

Comment: @cderv I just checked it. Thanks a lot for your support throughout.